# Raspberry boot files

Tags: boot, bootloader

I'm trying to boot the RasPi using specific files. I was following a tutorial and I had to compile some files using GCC. The problem is that this process doesn't provide a 'img' file and I don't know how to try the code in my RasPi.

The code I'm trying is [this](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/commit/910f42c1f2788ed61add61aaea42c720f82d2a17) .

To give you an example, the result of the GCC is: '.bin, .elf, .hex, .list and .o'. How can I run the code? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

What you appear to be doing is called bare metal programming, i.e. programming a box without having an operating system in charge.

If you Google Raspberry Pi bare metal you may find suitable examples.

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/introduction.html is a series of tutorials on bare metal with the Pi.  It seems to be more orientated to assembler rather than C.  However both C and assembler still need the same files on the Pi's SD card to boot.  It should give you the information you need.